# how to map native sql query to Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

lets say I have the following Entities

```
@Entity
public class Person{
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    private B b;
...
}

@Entity
public class B{
    private int id;
    private String x;
    private String y;
...
}
```

What I want to do is create a SELECT query from a join that returns columns from multiple tables. From the resultset I want to create Objects of Entity Person, process them and then persist them. Something like this

```
List<Person> list = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT p.firstName, p.lastName, st.entityB FROM someTable st JOIN Person p ON p.lastName = st.lastName").getResultList()
```

In the statement "someTable" is an unmanaged class, so there is no Entity class for that but it has a column with a reference to the Entity B.
This statement doesnt work but in my current solution I am just returning `List<Object[]>`. From there I could create a Person but would need to resolve the B Entity because I only get scalar types. Is there a cleaner way somehow, so that I could directly get a List of type Person and also the B Entity is resolved?

Comment: If you build 'Person' instances from scalar data, persisting it will introduce what seem to be to be duplicated people into your table; duplicate first/last names. Why not map 'someTable' as an entity? "select p, st.b from someTable st JOIN Person p ON p.lastName = st.lastName". Otherwise, see resultSetmappings which let you build into entities: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping

Comment: Thanks for your reply! the actual use case is way more complex than this, I just tried to simplify it and change the names due to confidentiality reasons. The reason there is no Entity for someTable is because it is just a temporary oracle table whose rows are removed on commit and it is only used for that one use case. But if there are no simpler solutions then I probably just have to create an Entity for that. Also will look into the resultSetMappings